# Can't Import Flink into Project

Tags: scala, build, apache-flink, flink-streaming

So I used this to install a sample Flink project. 
https://github.com/tillrohrmann/flink-project.g8

I am trying to use this template that lets me just start writing a Flink ingestion application and not have to worry about dependencies but it's backfiring. It turns out I can't find Flink when I try to sync with sbt (not going to lie but this part is even fuzzy for me). Was wondering if anyone knew how to make my project find Flink. Very excited to use the technology.

```
Error while importing sbt project:

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/Sam/IdeaProjects/cryptoingestion/project
[info] Set current project to cryptoingestion (in build file:/Users/Sam/IdeaProjects/cryptoingestion/)
>
[info] Defining */*:sbtStructureOptions, */*:sbtStructureOutputFile, root/*:shellPrompt
[info] The new values will be used by no settings or tasks.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to cryptoingestion (in build file:/Users/Sam/IdeaProjects/cryptoingestion/)
[info] Applying State transformations org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks from /Users/Sam/Library/Application Support/IdeaIC2017.3/Scala/launcher/sbt-structure-0.13.jar
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to cryptoingestion (in build file:/Users/Sam/IdeaProjects/cryptoingestion/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/Sam/IdeaProjects/cryptoingestion/}root...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.12.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.flink#flink-scala_2.12;1.3.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.flink#flink-scala_2.12;1.3.2 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.apache.flink#flink-scala_2.12;1.3.2
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/Sam/.ivy2/local/org.apache.flink/flink-scala_2.12/1.3.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-scala_2.12/1.3.2/flink-scala_2.12-1.3.2.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /Users/Sam/.sbt/preloaded/org.apache.flink/flink-scala_2.12/1.3.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////Users/Sam/.sbt/preloaded/org/apache/flink/flink-scala_2.12/1.3.2/flink-scala_2.12-1.3.2.pom
[warn] ==== Apache Development Snapshot Repository: tried
[warn]   https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/flink/flink-scala_2.12/1.3.2/flink-scala_2.12-1.3.2.pom
[warn] ==== Maven2 Local: tried
[warn]   file:/Users/Sam/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-scala_2.12/1.3.2/flink-scala_2.12-1.3.2.pom
[info] Resolving org.apache.flink#flink-streaming-scala_2.12;1.3.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.flink#flink-streaming-scala_2.12;1.3.2 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.apache.flink#flink-streaming-scala_2.12;1.3.2
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/Sam/.ivy2/local/org.apache.flink/flink-streaming-scala_2.12/1.3.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-streaming-scala_2.12/1.3.2/flink-streaming-scala_2.12-1.3.2.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /Users/Sam/.sbt/preloaded/org.apache.flink/flink-streaming-scala_2.12/1.3.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////Users/Sam/.sbt/preloaded/org/apache/flink/flink-streaming-scala_2.12/1.3.2/flink-streaming-scala_2.12-1.3.2.pom
[warn] ==== Apache Development Snapshot Repository: tried
[warn]   https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/flink/flink-streaming-scala_2.12/1.3.2/flink-streaming-scala_2.12-1.3.2.pom
[warn] ==== Maven2 Local: tried
[warn]   file:/Users/Sam/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-streaming-scala_2.12/1.3.2/flink-streaming-scala_2.12-1.3.2.pom
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.12.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.12.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.12;1.0.6 ...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.3 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.flink#flink-scala_2.12;1.3.2: not found
[warn]  :: org.apache.flink#flink-streaming-scala_2.12;1.3.2: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.apache.flink:flink-scala_2.12:1.3.2 (/Users/Sam/IdeaProjects/cryptoingestion/build.sbt#L22)
[warn]        +- com.cryptocorp:cryptoingestion_2.12:0.1
[warn]      org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-scala_2.12:1.3.2 (/Users/Sam/IdeaProjects/cryptoingestion/build.sbt#L22)
[warn]        +- com.cryptocorp:cryptoingestion_2.12:0.1
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last mainRunner/*:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last root/*:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last root/*:update' for the full output.
[error] (mainRunner/*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.flink#flink-scala_2.12;1.3.2: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.flink#flink-streaming-scala_2.12;1.3.2: not found
[error] (root/*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.flink#flink-scala_2.12;1.3.2: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.flink#flink-streaming-scala_2.12;1.3.2: not found
[error] (root/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.flink#flink-scala_2.12;1.3.2: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.flink#flink-streaming-scala_2.12;1.3.2: not found
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Dec 5, 2017 12:51:24 AM
```

edit: I got the project to build but I can not click around in my IDE. By that I mean when I try to move into a Flink class it can not find declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Flink Scala currently only supports Scala 2.10 and 2.11](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-scala), so you have to downgrade your Scala to one of those releases or use its Java interface.